# Join Instances of Animation Nodes/ Make them seperate Objects

Tags: animation-nodes

Is there a way to join the instances of an object from animation nodes to one mesh or convert them to independant "real" meshes?

I want to set only one boolean modifier object as an array of objects i created with animation nodes instead of applying n-modifiers for every cube.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the advanced node settings of the instancer node, you can use the *Unlink Instance From Node* operator to make the object independent of the node, then you can merge them and do whatever you like.

[image: Advanced Node Settings]

Answer (score 0):

Found the Solution(Dont know why it dindt work the first time):
1. AN autoexecution: Off
2. Clear Parent
3. Rename Object before executing AN again